# Devise 401 on Login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Devise for my site authentication. I have my user model set up as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :token_authenticatable, :confirmable 

  attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :college_id, :role
```

with the following routes:

```
  devise_for :users
  as :user do
    get 'sign_in'             => 'devise/sessions#new',       :as => :login
    post 'sign_in'            => 'devise/sessions#create',    :as => :user_session
    delete 'sign_out'         => 'devise/sessions#destroy',   :as => :logout
    get 'signup'              => 'devise/registrations#new',  :as => :signup
    get 'forgot_password'     => 'devise/passwords#new',      :as => :forgot_password
    get 'resend_confirmation' => 'devise/confirmations#new',  :as => :resend_confirmation
  end
```

and am receiving the following error:

```
Started POST "/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-06 19:57:34 -0400
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"iy0BI3A6zY5TTIJ2eYkOpgwFIFubO2O8wII8GAmjDmE=", "email"=>"user@cmu.edu", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "x"=>"-630", "y"=>"-434"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"iy0BI3A6zY5TTIJ2eYkOpgwFIFubO2O8wII8GAmjDmE=", "email"=>"user@cmu.edu", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "x"=>"-630", "y"=>"-434"}
```

This is showing up on the UI as "Invalid email or password." however I am sure that the entered password is correct, and the user exists in the database (verified via console). Devise does not seem to be making any queries to the database. Is this normal?

Any ideas? All help is appreciated.

Comment: Make sure your custom version of the devise controllers don't require you to be authenticated. Make sure they're extensions of the original devise base classes as well instead of just `ApplicationController`. It looks like it is setup so that the app is requiring you to be authenticated in order to authenticate. Could you show us your `SessionsController` ?

Comment: I don't have a custom SesssionController, I'm using the Devise controllers entirely.

Comment: hmm, why do you have the `as :users do` block then? For just plain old devise you just need the `devise_for :users`. Try commenting out the entire block and seeing if that helps?

Comment: I have the `as :users do` block to clean up the routes.

Comment: Is your session store type is cookies ?

Comment: @Btuman - unfortunately I did not. I believe I ended up scrapping the authentication and starting cleanly.

Answer (score 2):

try this in config/initializers/devise.rb

```
config.authentication_keys = [ :email ]
```

in user.rb  you need to add attr_accessor for :password as that is not saved to the database for security reasons

```
attr_accessor :password
```

Comment: I tried adding `attr_accessor :password` to user.rb, which caused the Users in my seed.rb to be created without an encrypted_password (empty "" instead of a hash like before).

Comment: Are you using gmail account's username and password for application login in case of admin ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. We're not using a gmail account at all.